# Error PowerShell remote stop process

Tags: powershell, process, remote-access

If I am trying:

```
Get-Process -c $comp -name chro* | Stop-Process
```

I have the following error:

> feature is not supported in remote machine

If I use the command `Get-Service` with pipeline for services it's working.
Last week I was able to stop a process with this command, but now I have this error for all the computers.

I tried also with `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process`:

```
(Gwmi Win32_Process -c $comp | ? {$_.ProcessName -like "*chr*"}).Terminate()
```

but it's not working, and I don't have errors.

I cannot use `Invoke-Command` because PSremoting is disabled.

Comment: What operating system and PowerShell versions are you running (local and remote)? Do you see anything in the logs of the remote host? Does your user account have admin access on the remote host? Does only terminating the remote process via WMI fail, or selecting as well?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i tried also in w7 -> w10 and w10 -> w10. I have admin acces, the get-service | stop-service remote it's working. To select remote process via WMI it's working, only .terminate() doesn't work. Is strange because last week everything was ok.

Comment: If the same code worked last week, but doesn't work now, something was changed on the systems. Check what that was. Also check what was changed before nothing was changed.

Comment: @ansgarwiechers unfortunately will be dificult because it's another company who manage this computers, servers, AD.

Comment: Are you able to call other methods remotely?  For example, does this work? `(Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_NTEventlogFile" -Filter {LogFileName = "Application"}).BackupEventLog("$env:TEMP\AppLog.bak")` It is possible someone has changed the WMI permissions.  You can check/reset them in the [MMC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg241210.aspx).

Comment: Other method remotly is working. Only this with process i have problem.